# How to stop barbell from being reracked during eccentric?

Tags: bench-press

On the bench press, I keep accidently reracking the barbell on the eccentric. I believe this is happening due to an exaggerated J curve  bar path when pressing. Any advice on how to solve?

---

A bit more explanation: When I try to push the barbell up from my chest, it goes so far back that it almost falls into the hook.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scoot down the bench.

If the bar is hitting the rack, you’re too far up the bench. Scoot down a little bit.

Comment: At the end of the lift, the bar stands a bit above the rack. Would your advice stay the same?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I don’t understand what you mean.